# How to host my jsp files in google appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

I wondered how to add my own JSP files in Google app engine. I created my account in Google app engine. I don't know  where to host my file and what is the url of my google appengine. Can anybody give me a simplified explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you do not upload JSP files, but rather complete WAR files. In any case here are the instructions for [uploading your web application](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading.html). Basically, you need to install their SDK and can then deploy using it (either from within Eclipse or via command line).

You may also want to read a bit about how to build your web project so that it will run under Google's app engine.